# AIR still possible to restart / reset app from code

Tags: memory, memory-management, air, reset, restart

Is it still possible to restart / reset an AIR app from code? cleaning up all memory resources, disposing of objects etc.

I found this but could not get it to work:

```
var mgr:ProductManager = new ProductManager("airappinstaller");
mgr.launch("-launch " + NativeApplication.nativeApplication.applicationID + " " +       NativeApplication.nativeApplication.publisherID);
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
```

source: http://creative-geeks.com/blog/2009/10/05/restart-an-adobe-air-application-with-code/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this is in your application descriptor:

```
<allowBrowserInvocation>true</allowBrowserInvocation>
```

Comment: A caveat - I got it to work just now in Air 2.6, but I could only restart the app once. A restarted app couldn't restart, only exit.

Comment: We can not enable 'allowBrowserInvocation' true for native captive run time application.Am I right?